# Android studio: Refractor name in class

Tags: android, android-studio

I copy/pasted a long function from my fragment to my activity realizing that I have to change `getContext();` to `getApplicationContext();`

Is there a way to refractor this for one class?

Comment: Why all these answers if this question was down voted twice :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Ctrl + R.

A replace all dialog will appear. From there you can manage.

Comment: will it replace this in my whole app or just in my class?

Comment: just in one class.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct, it will help others too.

Comment: It will not work for eclipse hotkeys in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Eclipse HotKeys then Ctrl+H

Or you can go to Edit>Find>Find in Path

Comment: Nice..But dont think anyone still using eclipse for android development. Still its good advice.

Comment: if you are a dev who switch between Eclipse and Android Studio then you probably would love to change your HotKeys in Android studio to match Eclipse HotKeys ... Thank IntelliJ for this heavenly gift :P

Comment: also, that's why I advised them to go use the `Edit>Find>Find in Path` instead of using the HotKeys :3

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Alt` `+` `J` , it will select all the similar words in that class and you can replace that code with new one.
Give it a try, it is shortcut shown in Google I/O.

Answer (score 0):

There are different keys usage for their respective editor tools and selection of keymaps:

**Android Studio** with **Default** keymap:

Use **Shift+F6**

[image]

Android Studio with **Eclipse** keymap:

Use **Alt+Shift+R**

[image]

You can check for the other editor tools keymap also by checking 
**File>>Settings>>Keymap>(Change here your keymap type)**